# Find element within div and add text with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write a small snippet of jQuery that validates my input fields. If they don't validate I want to write an error message to an empty `<p>` tag, only I can't seem to target it correctly. Can anybody see/explain where im going wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/xG2KS/19/

```js
$(".nextform").click(function() {
    var empty = $(this).parent().find("li input").filter(function() {
        return this.value === "";
    });
    if(empty.length) {
        $(this).find('p.feedback').html('error');
    }
});
```

```html
<div>
    <li><input type="text" /><br /></li>
    <li><input type="text" /><br /></li>
    <li><input type="text" /><br /></li>
    <li><p class="feedback"></p>
    <input type="submit" value="next" class="next" /></li>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code is not semantically correct, you cannot nest `<li>` tags within a `<div>` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In your sample HTML, there is no element with the class `.nextform`. Try selecting on `"input.next"` or, if you want to be more specific, `"input[type=submit].next"`.
- `<li>`'s should always be inside an `<ul>` or `<ol>`.
- `<input>`'s should only have `type="submit"` if they are inside a form and used to submit that form. If they are not, give them `type="button"`.
- Use [`.closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find the nearest ancestor of a certain type, e.g.: `$(this).closest("div")`.
- It's good practice to be as explicit as possible, so use: `if (empty.length > 0) { ... }`

http://jsfiddle.net/PPvG/xG2KS/38/

```js
$("input.next").click(function() {
    var parent = $(this).closest('div');
    var empty = parent.find("input[type=text]").filter(function() {
        return this.value === "";
    });
    var feedback = parent.find('p.feedback');
    if (empty.length > 0) {
        feedback.text('error');
    } else {
        feedback.text('');        
    }
});
```

```html
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><input type="text" /><br /></li>
        <li><input type="text" /><br /></li>
        <li><input type="text" /><br /></li>
        <li>
            <p class="feedback"></p>
            <input type="button" value="next" class="next" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".next").click(function() {
    var empty = $(this).parent().parent().find("li input").filter(function() {
        return this.value === "";
    });
    if(empty.length) {
        $(this).prev('p.feedback').html('error');
    }
});
```

I do not find `.nextform` but just `.next`, and should use `$(this).parent().parent()` because the click target is in `li`

Comment: While this is totally valid answer, I would recommend adding some kind of .container class to parent div. This way your code will not break in case you choose to wrap your submit button in some other tag.

Comment: You are right, my code base on the structure, using class might be better

Answer (score 0):

You should use prev()

```
$(".nextform").click(function() {
    var empty = $(this).parent().find("li input").filter(function() {
        return this.value === "";
    });
    if(empty.length) {
        $(this).prev('p.feedback').html('error');
    }
});
```

because find() looks for the descendants

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched
>   elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

Answer (score 0):

New Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kmendes/xG2KS/32/

This is how the code should look like:

```
$(".next").click(function() {
    var found = $(this).parents("div").find("li input").filter(function() {
        return this.value === "";
    });
    if(found.length) {
        $(this).parent().find('p.feedback').html('error');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".next").click(function() {
    var empty = $(this).parent().find("li input").filter(function() {
        return this.value === "";
    });
    if(empty.length) {
        $(this).parent().find('p.feedback').html('error');
    }
});
```